# Проблема при изменении списка классов HTML элемента

Tags: javascript, html

По какой-то причине при изменении списка классов некоторых HTML элементов изменения не сохраняются.
**Пример**:

```
<div class="card blue-grey darken-1" id="cardId">...</div>
<script>
  let el = document.getElementById('cardId');
  //el.classList.remove('darken-1');//Данная строка удалит класс из элемента "cardId"
  let card = new UiBilder({ element: 'cardId' });
  card.classes.del('darken-1');//Эта строка повлечет вызов метода apply для "cardId"
  ...
  apply (element) {
  ...
    console.log(element == document.getElementById('cardId'));//true
    console.log('del', entity, element.classList);//del darken-1 DOMTokenList(3) ["card", "blue-grey", "darken-1", value: "card blue-grey darken-1"]
    element.classList.remove(entity);
    console.log('after del', element.classList);//after del DOMTokenList(2) ["card", "blue-grey", value: "card blue-grey"]
  ...
  }
  ...
  console.log(card.element.classList)//DOMTokenList(3) ["card", "blue-grey", "darken-1", value: "card blue-grey darken-1"]
</script>
```

Как видно из последнего лога, класс `darken-1` вернулся, хотя других операций по изменению списка не производилось. Такое же поведение проявляется при добавлении класса.
**Вопрос**: в чем причина такого поведения списка классов и как это исправить?
Тестовая страница воспроизводящая данное поведение: [test.html](https://gist.github.com/x0k/735d7dda21d51fd29f0377d8fbbffa35)

Comment: Что бы вам помочь - надо видеть полный код. Скорее всего проблема в том, что удаляете класс у одного элемента, а проверяете потом другой элемент.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko полный код был приложен в виде тестовой страницы ([test.html](https://gist.github.com/x0k/735d7dda21d51fd29f0377d8fbbffa35)), но уже не важно, похоже, что я поспешил с вопросом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему, далее по коду идет изменение списка атрибутов, которое восстанавливает сохраненное состояние атрибута `class` т.к. изменений в список атрибутов не вносилось.
Проблему выявления бага вызвало то, что у некоторых элементов список классов все же изменялся, причина тому - порядок применения изменений списков где-то сначала изменялись атрибуты, а затем классы, где-то наоборот.
Проблема решена исключением атрибута `class` из списка отслеживаемых атрибутов.